# lambda_handler for cron expression

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Im running a Python Lambda using cron from event bridge every minute.

what should I pass to my function `lambda_handler(event, context):`

as event ? since there'e actually not real event, its just a cron job.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing anything to the handler? Are you asking purely for testing purposes?

Like you said, the event isn't important in this scenario, so your code can safely ignore the event, which means you don't need to pass anything when you are testing either.

When your Lambda function is deployed, AWS will be the one calling the `lambda_handler` function. That is the entry point to your code. You never call `lambda_handler` directly via your code.

Comment: I think OP is asking what will `event` correspond to when invoked via EventBridge cron

Comment: @Paolo if that's the case then "what should I pass to my function?" is a  really strange way of  wording that.

Comment: He's wondering if he needs to pass something because he doesn't think EventBridge will

Comment: Except there's no way he can intercept the request coming from EventBridge and pass anything into his function, which is what I'm trying to explain in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> since there'e actually not real event, its just a cron job.

There will be an event associated with the EventBridge request: it will be a `Scheduled Event` event.

Here's an example [from the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents.html):

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "region": "us-east-2",
  "detail": {},
  "detail-type": "Scheduled Event",
  "source": "aws.events",
  "time": "2019-03-01T01:23:45Z",
  "id": "cdc73f9d-aea9-11e3-9d5a-835b769c0d9c",
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:events:us-east-2:123456789012:rule/my-schedule"
  ]
}
```

You'll never need to specify neither the `event` nor the `context` arguments.